# Simple setState on object using hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

```js
const [state, setState] = useState({ city: '', country: '' });

const handleCityChange = event => {
  setState(prevState => {
    console.log(prevState);
    return { ...prevState, city: event.target.value };
  });
};

//...

<input
  type="text"
  placeholder="city"
  value={state.city}
  onChange={handleCityChange}
/>
```

I'm trying to destructuring `prevState`, which is an object, and update only the `city` property. On first keystroke, it's working fine without error, but as soon as I'm typing second letter, i will hit error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null

May I know which part is the null coming from? And from chrome console I see below warning not sure if it's related

> Warning: This synthetic event is reused for performance reasons. If you're seeing this, you're accessing the property `target` on a released/nullified synthetic event. This is set to null. If you must keep the original synthetic event around, use event.persist(). See https:...//react-event-pooling for more information.

**UPDATES**:
If we're not using `setState` functionally, then it's working fine?

```js
const handleCityChange = event => {
  setState({ ...state, city: event.target.value });
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An event has to be handled synchronously in React. You can extract the `value` from the target before you call `setState`:

```
const handleCityChange = event => {
  const { value } = event.target;
  setState(prevState => {
    return { ...prevState, city: value };
  });
};
```

Another way of going about it is to [`persist`](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html#event-pooling) the event, and it can be used asynchronously.

```
const handleCityChange = event => {
  event.persist();
  setState(prevState => {
    return { ...prevState, city: event.target.value };
  });
};
```

Comment: I just found out that without using functional setState, the problem will be eliminated? May I know how are they in different, if you care to explain a lil bit more about what's going on between them?

Comment: When you give a function as argument to `setState`, that function will be invoked asynchronously by React. Trying to dereference `event.target.value` in that function will not work, since you cannot use the event asynchronously.

Comment: Sort of getting the picture now. Gonna take some time to digest it. Thanks a lot!